# Should languages ​spoken by two similar races have the same protolanguage, or can they be not related by protolanguage?

Tags: fantasy-races, language, history, races, conlang

Should languages ​​spoken by two similar races have the same protolanguage, or can they be not related by protolanguage?
I guess they should be similar for example in phonetics or in some other features (grammar?). But should they be created from one protolanguage?

**P.S** Sorry for my English I'm not a native speaker.

[the same question on conlang.SE](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/should-languages-spoken-by-two-similar-races-have-the-same-protolanguage-or-ca)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "similar races." The term 'race' has multiple meanings in english. Depends upon the history. If they interacted a lot, then it's possible. If they are separated by an ocean,then it's doubtful. Lots of ways you could have the answer be 'yes' or 'no'. Think about how many proto-languages humans have.

Comment: Would you say that Hungarians and Finns are of the same race as English or Irish people? (For example, is [Anna Falchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Falchi) of the same race as [Kate Winslet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Winslet)?) And yet, the Hungarian and Finnish language are not genetically related to the English and Irish languages, at all.

Comment: @AlexP And what?

Comment: @user535733 oh, come on! Hollywood docos show that eventually everybody speak English. Even the borgs in StarTrek speak it. If some don't understand it, you just have to speak louder. (grin)

Comment: @user535733 "if they interacted a lot, then it's possible." — it means 
that they may be created from different protolangs or contrariwise?

Comment: So I have an example of two groups of nations which are very obviously of the *same* race and yet speak languages which are not related at all. So the answer to your question is very obviously, yes, they can be unrelated. In Europe we have *three* completely unrelated families of languages: Indo-European languages, Uralic languages, and Basque. (And Turkic languages, but they came later.) They do not share any linguistic genetic relationship.

Comment: @AlexP Ok, are you gonna write the answer?

Comment: No, I won't write an answer to a question with a very obvious answer.

Comment: @AlexP Why not?

Comment: OK, I wrote an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Languages are Inherited Historically

***Ancient History***
By no means all said and done, there are serious archaeolinguistic proposals delving into the deep past of human language. If you thought I-E was old at about 5 to 7 thousand years, then Nostratic at 12 to 15 thousand would be mind blowing. [Proto-World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Human_language) seeks to dig a little deeper, going back to the first spoken language maybe 100 to 200 thousand years ago.

Obviously, we don't really know how language actually arose and evolved *in the wild*. We also don't really know if the first Speakers came from a close community or were widespread in nature. Hence monogenesis vs polygenesis.

We could posit, however, that during various proposed [population bottleneck events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_bottleneck), that the surviving generations could likely be speaking but a single language. The implication: every subsequent language, no matter how seemingly unrelated on the surface is actually related deep in its bones.

If by "race" (one of the most nonsensical words ever applied to humanity) we mean nothing more than ethnicity, then it's clear we can logically propose that all later human ethnicities do in fact speak languages descending from a common protolanguage.

***Recent History***
Closer to our own time, we can see very clearly how people of different ethnicities come to be linguistically related through historical accident.

There is, within the Proto-Indo-European family a subfamily called Italic. Back in the day, its members included Oscan, Umbrian, Faliscan, and Latin. After the Latins gained supremacy and spread their empire around Europe, various other ethnicities came to speak it: Greek, Celtic, Germanic, Basque, and likely many more.

Moving forward, the modern French, Spanish, Italian, Portuguese and Romanians, regardless of their ethnic heritage, all speak languages descended from a common ancestor, in this case, Vulgar Latin.

***Future History***
There may come a time when humanity spreads out among the stars.

The future of human language will depend largely on the infrastructure of that future diaspora. (Will there be a vast galaxy spanning Empire where it takes only a few minutes or hours to travel from Rim to Rim, or some kind of lesser Federation where the diaspora is more limited but travel times are still reduced; or will there literally be one-way colony ships sent out into the largely unknown to risk their fates among the varied stars and planets of the cosmos?

If the latter, and if no practical means of shortening travel times can ever be devised, then we can posit that all future humans -- similar "races" as they shall become as genetic drift plays is part -- will speak a language descended from a single proto-language, which will, at the present time, most likely be English of Some Kind.

The specifics of that proto-language are not germane. What's important in this kind of mission, is that everyone working on the project Earthside and everyone within the colony ships can communicate effectively. But there will eventually come a time when radio signals sent from the ships will  fade and become unintelligible and even stronger signals sent from Earth may no longer be receivable.

Once all contact with Earth is sundered, the colonists will be on their own. So long as they comprise but a single community, their common language will likely survive. As the generations pass, education, communalism, mission needs will all conspire to keep the common language largely frozen. Once the humans arrive at and begin to colonise their destination world, they will eventually spread out.

As the future histories of those planets unfolds, into the thousands and myriades of years, their cultures will fall and rise again and their language will naturally evolve, split, become mutually unintelligible and they will lose all memory of Earth. They may in time even become physically quite different, yet they will all speak languages that ultimately derive from the speech used by the scientists, engineers and civilians taking part in the initial programme back here on Earth.

All those "similar races" spread throughout the near galaxy will come to speak wildly divergent languages that all derive historically & diachronically from a single Earth language.

Answer (score 8):

### Languages are not inherited biologically

What language a population speaks is not determined by the biological descent of that population; it is determined by the *history* of that population. That is, language is not transmitted via DNA, it is transmitted via education.

For example, I would assume that all European nations are of the same "race", whatever the word "race" is supposed to mean. At least, all European nations look pretty similar physically, and have pretty similar cultures. Moreover,  at least in America, that "race" is called Caucasian, which makes me believe that Americans perceive actual Caucasians (for example, Chechens, Circassians, Georgians or Dagestanis) to be of the same "race" as western Europeans.

And yet in Europe we have three completely unrelated groups of languages: Indo-European languages (most of them), Uralic languages (e.g., Finnish, Estonian or Hungarian), and the Basque language. The actual Caucasians speak two more completely unrelated families of languages: Caucasian languages (e.g., Circassian or Chechen) and Kartvelian languages (e.g., Georgian). That's *five* unrelated language families.

Then we have Turkic languages, and most people would agree that Turks look very very similar to Europeans. Semitic languages, and most people would agree that Arabs and Hebrews are quite similar physically with Europeans. And so on.

Therefore the answer is that, very obviously, two "similar races" do not have to speak related languages. It may very well happen that they speak completely unrelated languages.

### Excursus

It does not matter one jot whether the two languages are "related by protolanguage" or not. Linguists can detect the common descent between languages very very much farther away from the point where normal people won't perceive any relationship. Romance languages, Germanic languages (including English), Slavic languages (including Russian), Iranian languages (including Persian and the Pashto of Afghanistan) and Indo-Arian languages (including Hindi) are actually all related, being ultimately descended from Proto-Indo-European; and yet, the knowledge of their common descent is utterly useless: they do not sound the same, they are in no way similar, and the people speaking them have no consciousness of any sort of common culture.

Languages descended from the same protolanguage may have similar phonemic systems, or they may not. They may have similar grammars or they may not. For example, English and Russian are related, the relationship is not all that distant, and it's in fact quite obvious; their most recent common ancestor language was spoken not more than four or five thousand years ago. And yet, there is very very little similarity between the phonemic systems or the grammars or English and Russian.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica You generally should not accept this fast. In this case it should be fine (really good answer) but **in general**.

Comment: Excellent answer. I suppose you could cover off the ambiguity of what's meant by 'races' by saying 'If by races you mean different species as is common in fantasy, then there's even less of a reason for them to share a common language.'